# Check for checked checkbox validatejs

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm using **validatejs** for my forms validations. How can I check if my **checkbox** is **checked or not**? Or any other attribute?

https://validatejs.org/

Comment: What have you already tried?  Did you read the documentation at that link that you posted?  A more specific question will get you a more useful response.

Comment: Yes I read the documentation, but still cannot understand how it works with checkbox.

Comment: I have this code now `var constraints2 = {
      checkbox: {
        presence: true
      }
    };
    $("#agreement-modal").click(function(){
        var agr = $("#agreement-modal");
        var checkCheckBox = validate({checkbox: agr}, constraints2);

        console.log(checkCheckBox);

    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want the value whether checkbox is checked or not you can do it in plain JavaScript as `document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").checked` or simply using id `document.querySelector("#id_of_chkbx").checked`

Comment: This is good idea, but other elements of for is checked by validatejs, the only thing left is this checkbox.

Comment: Actually this answer should be deleted, the question was - how do this with validatejs not a vanila js